# Can I use a username based In-App Purchase system?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I have to implement a way to buy an In-App Purchase item (it's a subscription) but not AppleID based.
In other words I need to login in my app and buy the item with my login info. If i change user (but not the AppleID in the AppStore) I want to be able to buy another subscription. Of course the same user should not be able to pay twice but I can prevent by checking its subscription status on the server.
How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apple will reject your app if you try to bypass their appleID based in -app purchase system.

Comment: I know. That's why I'm searching for a way to use In-App Purchase trying to suit my needings. Of course I will buy with my AppleID but i want to be able to buy again the subscription with another user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want auto-renewable subscription then you can go with Consumable In-App Purchase.
You have to manage user Subscription on server side.

Comment: Yes, I think it's the best solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: hi Adriano Tornatore, I have exactly same need for my app. Can you share your experience on that?